# how can i add a style to "groupingName" using Jqgrid grouping method?

Tags: jqgrid, styles

how can i add a `font-size:bold` to the groupingName using jqgrid ?

```
$("#ddGrupare").change(function () {
        var groupingName = $(this).val();

        if (groupingName != -1) {
            $("#list2").jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', groupingName, {
                 groupOrder : ['desc']
            });
        }else{
            $("#list2").jqGrid('groupingRemove');
        }
});
```

this is my code and i want to add css to groupingName. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS to your stylesheet:

```
tr.jqgroup td {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

Make sure your stylesheet where you define this CSS rule is included **AFTER** the jQGrid stylesheet.

Comment: it works, but not for font-weight. its work for eg: color:red;

Comment: .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgroup td {
    font-weight: bold !important;
} this one works for me

Comment: @Chester I updated my code above... that should work for you!

Comment: @Chester If this answer helped solve your problem, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a style via the `.jqgroup` class that is applied to your group headers.